# PHP memory_get_usage(false) vs memory_get_usage(true)

Tags: php, memory-leaks

Can somebody clarify what's the exact difference of the `$real_usage` parameter for `memory_get_usage()`?

The [manual](https://www.php.net/memory_get_usage) states:

> Set this to TRUE to get the real size of memory allocated from system.
> If not set or FALSE only the memory used by emalloc() is reported.

But what's the difference?
**Which value is comparable to the `memory_limit` INI setting**?

For some long running scripts I get something like 250MB real usage and just 50MB emalloc usage. How is that possible?

I'm trying to analyze some memory leak problems and `memory_get_usage()` is an important indicator for me that I need to fully understand. Thanks.

Comment: You might have gone through this still sharing the links.
[memory mangement](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/php/ch14_05.htm) and [PHP basics of memory](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.memory.management.php#internals2.memory.management.apis) .. Please read the last sentence of 2nd paragraph from 2nd link

Comment: Link added. You mean *"When PHP is built in debug mode (--enable-debug), detected leaks are reported, in a perfect world they would never get to deployment. "* ? How does that answer my question?

Comment: I think I have misread it "build in" as "in". I apologies for that. I read it as we can set debug mode ON to see memory leak

Answer (score 8):

The real memory is the amount of memory that's reserved for the PHP process. PHP reserves memory in large chunks, and this will be <= memory_limit, and may increase during the script's execution. Eg. If it fills up a chunk, and you then try to assign to a new variable, it will reserve another chunk.

If you set the parameter to FALSE, it only reports the amount of memory that PHP is actually using inside the reserved memory. This will increase every time you assign to a new variable, or call a function etc.

If you're interested in the amount of memory that is actually being used, then you'll want the real memory.

If you're debugging, or trying to tune a piece of code, you'll probably be more interested in the emalloc() memory. This would allow you to check the memory before and after an assignment or function call and calculate the delta.

Comment: And which parameter setting do I need to detect if I'm about to reach the `memory_limit` INI setting? *(for internal caching I need a lot of memory and I need to free parts of the cache when necessary to avoid to exceed the memory limit)*

Comment: That depends on how close you want to let it get to the memory_limit setting. I'd probably suggest to set the parameter to FALSE to get the emalloc() usage.

Comment: Based on my testing (in PHP 5.5) the `memory_limit` INI setting is based on the value of `memory_get_usage(true)`.  So your script may actually be using many KBs less than the maximum before it crashes. 
```<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '500K');
echo "memory limit: " . ini_get('memory_limit') . "\n";

$x = 'A';
for($i = 0 ; $i <= 100; $i++) {
 echo memory_get_usage(false). " vs " . memory_get_usage(true). "\n";
 $x = $x . 'A';
 
}
```
output:
memory limit: 500K
226688 vs 262144
226992 vs 262144

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 512000 bytes exhausted